# How to UNDO in Bash?

Tags: bash, undo

I accidentially copied my whole home directory into one of my subdirectories, causing me to exceed my disk quota on a server.

Or does anyone know how to undo a command in general?

Comment: In addition to [*"Here's a nickle, kid. Get yourself a better computer."*](http://tomayko.com/writings/that-dilbert-cartoon) old unix programers and admins like to say *"You recover from your backup. You **do** have a backup don't you?"*. Though in this case it is only the original contents of the sub-directory that are likely to be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash is just a command-line interpreter - it does what you tell it to do and doesn't have an undo helper program. You're best of just deleting the subdirectory with something like:

```
chmod -R 775 ~/yoursubdir && rm -rf ~/yoursubdir
```

Comment: Can you explain what the first part of that command does? Thanks :)

Comment: That first part is setting the rwx (read, write, execute) permissions to your user and group - for all the files and folders just to be sure you will not encounter permission problems upon deleting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's no such thing. If there was, that would be pretty interesting.

For your case you can just remove the subdirectory

```
rm -rf /path/to/subdirectory
```

But be careful with that command, as it can fully delete any files from the sub-directory without any confirmation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the shell, you are the undo.  The opposite of copying is deleting (rm), so delete the copies.

I recommend installing the trash-cli package, and then setting these Bash aliases:

```
alias rm='trash'
alias rrm='rm -i'
```

Of course, in your case, since you're out of disk space, you probably don't want to trash the files first.  Even so, it's a good practice to use the trash.